# Plans (if any) and expected timeline of support for the AVIF format by the graphicx package

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

The [AVIF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1#AV1_Image_File_Format_(AVIF)) for photos is claimed to be up to 50%  smaller than traditional `JPEGs` for photos & a further 20% smaller than the `.webp` format.

VLC, Chrome, Firefox, Netflix, GIMP & various other important projects is already supporting it, or scheduled to support it in the near future. There are plans to make AVIF as the default format for camera pictures.

I was wondering if the LaTeX graphics package will support either `.webp` or `.avif` sometime in the future? This will make PDFs smaller, especially for a thesis with many photos of experimental lab setups & field photographs.

Comment: How would it make PDFs smaller? Unless PDF supports it, any inclusion will require re-encoding to JPEG

Comment: the graphicx package doesn't really support any format at all, it just passes on an include request to the back end (dvips or dvisvg or pdflatex or xdvipdfmx etc, so the answer depends on which system you use (but likely to be no for all of them I would guess) and as Joseph says, as with png files, the graphics will have to be converted before being included in the final pdf

Comment: Alright. Even if it doesn't make the PDFs smaller, at least the user can directly `\includegraphics` an AVIF file (as David says, through re-encoding when pdflatex is run). Will save users from manually converting 30 images from AVIF to other formats.

Comment: it is easy to script the conversion as part of your document process and this is far simpler than building the conversion into pdftex itself which would mean compiling and testing convertors for every platform on which pdftex is compiled, this is no different from historic requests to support gif or eps with pdftex or support png with latex+dvips or other formats